# Hiding a form with jQuery but don't want it to hide when autocomplete comes up

Tags: jquery, forms, autocomplete, mouseleave

I've set a form to fadeOut using jQuery when the mouseleaves the form which has an id of #loginform_top. This works ok but as this form is a login box when firefox pops up the autocomplete detials for the input fields in this form the act of moving the mouse onto the autocomplete hides my form. Is there away to be able to select the autocomplete without hiding the form. Thanks for looking at this. I'm using the following code:

```
  $('#loginform_top').hide(); 
  $('.loginToggle').mouseover(function() { 
    if(!$('#loginform_top:visible').length)
    {
      $('#loginform_top').fadeIn('fast'); 
    }
  });
  $('#loginform_top').mouseleave(function() { 
   $('#loginform_top').fadeOut('fast') 
  });
```

});

Comment: I got round this in the end by setting autocomplete to off for the input field

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try making the form bigger by adding `<br />`s inside of it or setting its height style attribute. This could be caused by the mouse leaving the form when clicking the auto-complete options (which is what I think you described above).

I haven't checked, but you might be able to combine this with onblur="" that says when the textbox is unselected. Then, your other JavaScript code can reference a variable defined there.

Comment: Hello yes it's caused by the mouse leaving the form when clicking the auto-complete options. At the moment when you click the auto-complete option it think's it's left my <form id="loginform_top"> and hides the form. I want to stop it doing this.

Comment: As I said, make the form bigger.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a hack, but what if you kicked off a setTimeout in the mouseleave handler that delays hiding the form to give the user a chance to deal with the autocomplete.

Alternatively, you could provide an "X" or something to let the user dismiss the form if they choose not to login, rather than using mouseleave. This assumes that *not* logging in is a valid option.

Comment: Hello I tried seTimeout hack but the problem with this hack is the form still fades out after the timeout. If the user doesn't hit the submit button before the timeout has ended then form fades out still. If you set the interval to high number then when the mouseleaves the form the then the form takes ages to fade out which feels wong. There form is a drop down menu so the user can close it by hitting the button they used to open it. However I also want the form to dissappear when they mouseleave the form. Is there a way to autocomplete not be thought of as leaving the form?

Comment: I don't think so. The autocomplete is rendered by the browser itself, not as part of the document, so detecting it from the document is a problem. Also, coding this specifically for one browser may not be optimal.